# Declaring Variables in the .data Versus on the Stack - ASM

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to understand in which cases you would want to declare variables in the .data section of my assembly program and using it for the procedures needed, over instantiating local variables on the stack and vice versa. Is it just that declaring variables in the .data section is only appropriate for smaller programs? Is it too easy to change the variable elsewhere or end up with a random value?

Comment: Data segment variables are global, stack variables are local. Data segment variables are faster because you already have their offsets. Stack variables are slower because it is necessary to get their offsets manually.

Comment: Both have some risk of overwriting or randomizing, when you access them with registers, like SI, DI, BX (for data segment) and SP, BP (for stack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables created in the *.data* section are directly accessable from every procedure. *LOCAL* variables are only present in the specific procedure and getting popped from the stack as soon as the procedure ends.
What do you mean exactly with "end up with a random value"?

Comment: I meant that it's more easy to accidentally use it in a different section and ruin your result.

Comment: When you're declaring your variables you should be aware of not using it in the wrong way. What i sometimes do is creating something like "prefixes" example your file is called: memory.asm, then i'd name the variables MEMORY_VariableName or something like that.